# Build error after initialising a project with OpenWrap

Tags: openwrap

I'm getting this error when I build my project in Visual Studio after initialising OpenWrap.

> The
>   "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration"
>   task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "WrapDescriptor".

Any idea what is wrong? I'm just following the guide on the OpenWrap [wiki](https://github.com/openrasta/openwrap/wiki).

Comment: is your project in the /src folder?

Comment: Yes it is, although not directly? Its  here src\MvcApplication\MvcApplication.sln. The init must have at least partially worked as the .proj file was altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in responding, christmas and all that :)

We've fixed a whole bunch of bugs with the latest release. I'd recommend updating your packages to the latest version.

Also make sure that your package descriptor is in the root of your project. It currently only support descriptors up to a couple of levels, if you're too nested it won't be found. You can alter your msbuild file to change the location of the descriptor by using the OpenWrap-DescriptorPath property, or you can fill-in a bug on github so we can address that scenario.

Comment: Thanks Seb, Updating Openwrap and/or removing a level of nesting did the trick